# Identity Server4 User to select account after login

Tags: c#, oauth, openid-connect, identityserver4

I have successfully implemented Identity Server4 to allow authentication and authorization, and it works great.

Now I have a requirement where the user logins in using their username and password, and then he/she might have access to multiple accounts. So they choose any account that they prefer, and then only the token should be created for that specific account.

I assume that I could do the same in Identity Server3 using Partial Login. But I don't see its there in Identity Server4 anymore. How do I implement such a feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IdentityServer4 you are responsible of the UI. You can download a starter UI from here:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI

In there you will find the login page, a corresponding account controller and more. If you want to add some custom UI, simply extend the starter UI.

Comment: What i was really wanting to know was more about the code flow rather than UI itself. Generally, when u pass the username and password to the IDSRV, it immediately returns the token. How can we alter this to bring the account selection page. Hope i am clear now

Comment: Use one of the interactive flows like implicit or hybrid. Check the samples.